# having error with mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this is my code and im having the problems for 2 hours now

```
Dim Query As String


 con.Open()
Query = "INSERT INTO  `" & finalTableName & "` VALUES" & _
        "(" & _
        " '" & varDateTime & "'," & _
        " '" & varComputer & "'," & _
        " '" & vard & "'," & _
        " '" & varll & "' ," & _
        " '" & varPp & "'," & _
        " '" & varVv & "' ," & _
        " '" & varIi & "' ," & _
        " '" & varIc & "'," & _
        " '" & varPc & "'," & _
        " '" & varSs & "'," & _
        " '" & varRd & "'," & _
        " '" & varIpd & "'," & _
        " '" & varMg & "'," & _
        " '', " & _
        "  '" & varRuleId & "', " & _
        " '" & varDateUploaded & "' " & _
        ")"

Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) Then


End If

con.Close()
```

This is the problem that im having

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dd', 'Deleted',
'344', '',   '4',  '2014-03-05 15:29:37' )' at line 1
```

Comment: What is the actual query this code creates?

Comment: not knowing the table it's inserting makes this a guessing game

Comment: another query actually pass this part to 'dd', 'Deleted', '344', '', '4', '2014-03-05 15:29:37' and then this part insert those data to the database, the others goes well and is insert in the database but this specific part shows this error

Comment: I strongly recommend that you look in to using SQL parameters and get rid of the hassle of getting the query syntax correct with having to quote and double-quote so much.

Comment: "dd varchar(50)," & _
        "cc varchar(50)," & _
        "dd varchar(50)," & _
        "ld varchar(50)," & _
        "platform varchar(50)," & _
        "vid varchar(50)," & _
        "ide varchar(50)," & _
        "isdf varchar(50)," & _
        "pd varchar(500)," & _
        "sd varchar(50)," & _
        "rd varchar(50)," & _
        "ids varchar(50)," & _
        "md varchar(50)," & _
        "ld int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," & _
        "rd varchar(50)," & _
        "ddd varchar(50)," & _
        "Primary Key (logId)" & _
        ")" table structure

Comment: This code **WILL** be vulernabe to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: What is the value of varSs when you get the error? Can you show the query right before you run it and display it here?

Answer (score 1):

Use command parameters

```
Dim Query As String

Query = "INSERT INTO `" & finalTableName & _
    "` VALUES(@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, '', @14, @15)"

Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

cmd.AddWithValue("@1", varDateTime);
cmd.AddWithValue("@2", varComputer);
cmd.AddWithValue("@3", vard);
cmd.AddWithValue("@4", varll);
cmd.AddWithValue("@5", varPp);
cmd.AddWithValue("@6", varVv);
cmd.AddWithValue("@7", varIi);
cmd.AddWithValue("@8", varIc);
cmd.AddWithValue("@9", varPc);
cmd.AddWithValue("@10", varSs);
cmd.AddWithValue("@11", varRd);
cmd.AddWithValue("@12", varIpd);
cmd.AddWithValue("@13", varMg);
cmd.AddWithValue("@14", varRuleId);
cmd.AddWithValue("@15", varDateUploaded);

con.Open()
If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then


End If
con.Close()
```

The parameters will automatically be add the right way correponding the column type (text as text, numbers as numbers, dates as dates).

Also I recommend to add the column names part. This makes the command safer. If you later add or remove columns and the column order is changed, it will still work or at least throw an exception and not silently insert a value into a wrong column.

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the ` and use ' instead.
As in:

```
`" & finalTableName & "`
```

should be

```
'" & finalTableName & "'
```

Comment: No, this is MySql. He wants backticks to indicate a table name, not single quotes for a string literal.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is completely legitimate. When I use back ticks in VB.Net I get errors from MySQL, when I replace them with single quotes, it works. This is a legitimate problem with VB.Net and MySQL.

Comment: You need the single quotes for string values. If you're trying to inject a table name in the query, like he is here, you want backticks. And even the string values are suspect: if you're doing that as part of string concatenation for user input, your code is horribly vulnerable to injection attack.